# How to debug a cmake dll target in visual studio without generating solution file?

Tags: visual-studio

With the solution file I can change the `command` in the debugging settings to launch the exe that uses the dll, but how to do this when opening the cmake project directly in visual studio (that is without generating the solution file)? `launch.vs.json` doesn't seems to have relevant settings.